Override MDM-controlled notification settings
We get Macs issued from my workplace, which has MDM (mobile device management) on it. When there is a scheduled system update upcoming in a couple of weeks I'll get daily reminders about it, which is super distracting and obnoxious. The notification settings in System Preferences for the MDM app (Kandji) is locked.
Is there any way I can tweak these settings or otherwise turn the notifications off?

Show us your work with focus mode - that’s going to be the answer here !

Unlikely. I’ve not seen focus mode help here but try that and total do not disturb.
Can you ask them to put your Mac in a group that suppresses these alerts? Most MDM have a group for lab machines and others so that they can push these to the targets and not all managed devices.

I've tried talking to the person responsible, but he doesn't seem too keen on making changes for me unfortunately… I had hoped there were workarounds that could override the notification settings. When we previously had a locked 2 min delay before the screensaver turned on, I could use a third-party app to keep the Mac awake, for example.

@Simon If you enable do not disturb, will that harm you from other notifications? I’m guessing you can’t work effectively offline, either. An MDM push is hard to block since that is designed to always be delivered and acted upon. For remote lock, for remote wipe, for immediate security push.

it might be that I can use the focus modes! I've made a new mode where it will only silence the Kandji thing (which I was able to select from the list). I will report back when I've had it on for a while!

Definitely make a proper answer now. Document what you set up and people will give you more advice if they have a better option.

Seems like it didn't work completely as expected, as the notifications about system updates still come from System Preferences, which is an app I can't select in the list of apps to silence…
